# How to solve the roots of following cubic equation $a^3-6a^2+9a-4=0$

Tags: roots, cubics

How to solve the roots of following cubic equation

$$a^3-6a^2+9a-4=0$$

I am solving  ***roots of characteristics equation***

so I use casio 991ms calculator so it gave me roots $-0.355301,3.177650,3.1776506$

please help me with this

Comment: Your Casio, or something you entered into it, is wrong.  The coefficients add up to $0$ which should be a dead giveaway for one root.  In a correct solution you should find all roots are whole numbers!

Comment: Rectify the Casio!

Comment: Better to do by hand in the old fashioned way. HINT  Sum of coefficients = zero means $(x-1)$ is a root.. which you missed two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$a^3-6a^2+9a-4=a^3-2a^2+a-4a^2+8a-4=a(a-1)^2-4(a-1)^2$$

Comment: By guessing, since $a=1$ is a root, dividing $a^3-6a^2+9a-4|a-1$ we obtain $a^2-5a+4=(a-1)(a-4)$.

Comment: how do u entered this equation(while answering) bcoz i used html(while typing question) is there any alternative to(easy way )to enter the equation(while asking question on this site) i am new to this site

Comment: @MandarSant Just type "a^3-6a^2+9a-4=a^3-2a^2+a-4a^2+8a-4=a(a-1)^2-4(a-1)^2" and use the marker "$" at  the biginning and at the end.

Comment: @MandarSant If you push on "edit" commend you can see all the full text. As an alternative you can copy that through the right button of the mouse.

Answer (score 4):

you did something wrong, not sure calculator issue or a typo.

For cubic equations, if it's a setup question better to try a simple root first by inspection.

Hint: try $a=1$.

Once you have one value, you can reduce to second order and find the other two roots.

Comment: it only gave me 2 roots 1,4 how to find 3rd root

Comment: Divide out the $a=1$ root by dividing by $a-1$. Solve the quadratic equation by factoring, completing the square, or the quadratic formula for the remaining roots.  You should find your "missing root" is actually a double root.  The problem is testing your ability to incorporate a double root into your solution, which your book should have told you how to do.

Answer (score 2):

$a^3-6a^2+9a-4=0$

$a(a^2+6a+9)=4$

$a(a-3)^2=4\times 1^2$

$a_1=4$

$\frac{a^3-6a^2+9a-4}{a-4}= a^2-2a+1$

$a^2-2a+1=0$

$(a-1)^2=0$

$a_2=a_3=1$

Comment: $a^3-7a^2+11a-5=0$         can you help me with this?

Comment: Like previous equation the sum of coefficients of terms of polynomial is 0, i,e. $1-7+11-5=0$, that is $a=1$is a solution.Divide $a^3-7a^2+11a-5$ by (a-1) you get an equation of degree 2 which can be solved easily.

Answer (score 1):

Get the critical values of the equation by testing for a number that produces the result 0. Then use that equation to divide the polynomial, you'll be left with a quadratic equation. I think you can continue from there

Comment: "Critical values" normally refers to places where the derivative vanishes or doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers $1,4$ are roots of your equation. Can you find the rest? In case you want to have a view of the graph you can use a nice software like "desmos".

Comment: i want 3 roots not only 1 and 4

Comment: There are no more, actually...the $1$ is double. See gimusi factorization, please.

Comment: how to  identified which root is double using calculator

Comment: You only think you want three roots.  See my comment under another answer.

Comment: Nice question, but I do not know about Casio calculators...